# Responsive css problems in mobile

Tags: css, web, responsive-design

I having a responsive problem - i have to0 much empty space from the element to the end of the window. when im trying to see my site on a mobile phone, this the code i put in my document.(in the head part)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

this is the link for the page.

https://b3fcadc823747b188593835d025db80cc2776431-www.googledrive.com/host/0B6vlu2kaM73TQmZwSndCeTJpd1U/jenny%20web%20site/

thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have this piece of code:

```
  #ways {
    position: relative;
    right: 170px;
    width: 900px;
  }
```

Because of this big width there is your issue.

Then you have this issue:

```
.text-muted {
    position: relative;
    top: 300px;
    right: 500px;
}
```

Because of big "right" there is much space too.